# Is it possible to access file system in Mac App without file browser dialogue

Tags: macos, mac-app-store, read-write, entitlements

In our Mac App we have following credential to entitlement.plist which enables us to read/write to user's file system followed by file browser dialogue:

```
com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write
```

That does mean we able to read/write a file/folder if once accessed by file browser dialogue. We never able to read/write to files/folder if not accessed by file browser dialogue at least once in an application life cycle.

I didn't found any other possible credential too to entitlement.plist which can enable us read/write to files/folder by completely removing any use of file browser dialogue. Is there any way we can achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

I assume your app is Sandboxed and if so, it's only possible to access the filesystem as defined [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html):

> **Powerbox and File System Access Outside of Your Container Your**
>
> sandboxed app can access file system locations outside of its
>   container in the following three ways:
>
> - At the specific direction of the user
> - By using entitlements for
>     specific file-system locations (described in [Entitlements and System
>     Resource Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW1))
> - When the file system location is in certain
>     directories that are world readable
>
> The OS X security technology that interacts with the user to expand your sandbox is called Powerbox. Powerbox has no API. Your app uses Powerbox transparently when you use the `NSOpenPanel` and `NSSavePanel` classes.

Comment: Well, our application is an IDE which involves arbitrary file/folder access by user or automatic. By automatic I mean accessing files/folders through previously opened items which need not to open a file browser dialogue. The location can be anywhere in user's system. I noticed that setting app sandbox to false enabling me access arbitrary files/folders without file browser dialogue. Is such entitlement value is acceptable at all?

Comment: @SantanuKarar Yes, however you won't be able to publish your app on the Mac App Store.  If you are accessing files previously selected by the user then you can use security-scoped bookmarks to "save" that permission to access those files between sessions.

Comment: Your latter suggestion makes much sense to me. We was already using com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.document-scope and com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope as True but the solution suggested sounds something different. Can you give me some more guidance on how this can be achieved - or any article link?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the whole point of Sandboxing is to actually don't allow you to access user's files without their knowledge.

The only thing you can probably do is to use `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.*` entitlements to access some *specific* (read *hard-coded*) file system locations. You can learn more about temporary exceptions here: [App Sandbox Temporary Exception Entitlements](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html).

But keep in mind that you'll have to explain to the Apple Review Team why you need those exceptions in the first place.